# List of file and directory in directory in MAC OSX and Linux with Java

Tags: java, linux, macos, list, file

hello guys i have this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

                  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                      if(!listOfFiles[i].isHidden()) {
                           files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                           List=List+files+"?:";
                      }                                              
                  }
                  else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                        File Test = new File(listOfFiles[i]+"\\");
                        File [] Rec= Test.listFiles();
                        if(Rec!=null) 
                            if(!listOfFiles[i].isHidden()) {
                                files=listOfFiles[i].getName();
                                List=List+files+"*:";
                            }
                        }
          }
```

this code in windows return the real directory and all file in folder' but on mac and linux i see only the files..
why?

Comment: Possibly due to mac and linux using forward slash as a directory delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `"\\"` with `File.separator`.

```
File Test = new File(listOfFiles[i]+File.separator);
```

This will then work in a cross-platform way: it'll use `\` on Windows, but `/` on Mac and Linux.

One note of caution: there's also a `File.pathSeparator`, and that has a tempting name for what you're doing, but it's not the right thing. It's used for separating lists of paths, and it's `;` on Windows and `:` on Mac and Linux.

By the way, it's really not considered a good idea to have instance variables that start with a capital letter (like `Test` above). Class names should be capitalized, but not method names or field names.